# Can an inline-flex element adjust to the width of a vertical-rl child element in Firefox?

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-text

I have a `div` with `display: inline-flex` that contains a `div` with vertical text using `writing-mode: vertical-rl`.  In Chrome and Safari, the outer `div` expands to fit the width of the inner `div`, but in Firefox the width of the outer `div` collapses to 0 and the inner `div` overflows.  Is there a cross-browser way to make the outer `div` respect the width of the inner `div`?

| Chrome 103 & Safari 15 | Firefox 103 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: text is contained] | [image: text overflows] |

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.inner {
  border: 2px dotted black;
}

.vertical {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Hello world</div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner vertical">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found [an open bug in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1767091) that appears to be related.  "We probably behave as we do because, for the vertical-WM element, an 'auto' width is unresolvable without actually fully laying out its contents, and we haven't done that yet at the point where we're deciding where it will go with respect to potentially-colliding floats." It seems Firefox waits a weirdly long time to determine the width of `writing-mode: vertical-rl` elements, while other browsers do not.